# What is considered enough validation within excel dataset

Tags: sql, excel, validation

When you are providing a report to an end user and you want to validate the report against the system and database (checking that your SQL code is pulling the details accurately), what is considered enough validation on the output Excel file?

For example:

- 10% in 100 would be 10
- 10% in 1000 would be 100 seems reasonable
- 10% in 1,000,000 would be 100,000 and seems completely unreasonable.

Is there a template or scale to validate across large datasets for human validation? Has anyone done or seen something like this before that I could use as a guide?

Comment: So, if it was your pay, and it is one of the 100 that fails is that ok?

Comment: @SolarMike I see your point lol in the 10 example we would just validate all. But in the case of 1 million rows. How do you best validate your data?

Comment: So this is statistics... checking the largest or most consequential and a random sample of others seems like a common sense approach.

Comment: @SolarMike Could you explain this in more detail? Sounds exactly what I need. How do I quantify it. Also knowing that datasets can vary in size that I will be validating

Comment: Basic maths from now on... LARGE() can give you the largest or a specific value such as 4th largest and a random selection based on the range of data...

Answer (score 0):

Now when you say validate against the database, the data you are giving has already been pulled from the database I am assuming. So is the question how to validate data that was input or validate that the queries are accurate?

If it's the first, the only real way to do this is to have controls for type of entry (IE: string, date, integer validation.)

If it's the second, then you should evaluate it on some quantitative criteria. For example, If I am trying to validate that I sold 100 computers last month and I have hard receipts for those 100 then I can query to ensure that this is reflective of the actual truth. Beyond that, you could have controls to make sure reports don't report duplicates and so on and so forth, but that has more to do with just general administration of input.

Comment: hi @Alexander yes already pulled from the database. It would be more validate that the queries are accurate or reflective of how the system has entered the data. I understand users can input in different ways. My main question is more just I have wrote my SQL query, several joins, filters, sorts, case statements. Extract it to excel with 20,000 rows. How do I then say to the user with confidence I have checked 2% of the 20,000 and they reflect what is on the system. I understand my query can be wrong sometimes, thats fine but how much is considered enough validation?

Comment: Hello, I see. So when you run a query on a database, it is operating all of the same parameters on your dataset, that means that no matter if you check 5 or 50 or 5,000, you will still get the same result. You can check 100 or whatever number you pick (I always make it over 10 for no specific reason) because the query will operate the same on the entire dataset regardless. You can have confidence in the exported data by just checking some and you will know that there can be no deviation other than data that was input invalidly, not that you did anything wrong with the query. Hope that helps.